# AWS s3cmd "exclude" not working?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have been spending the last 15 minutes trying to figure out how to get `exclude=` to work.

I want to upload all my `static/` folder to s3 except for the folder `static/js`.

I have tried the following:

- `s3cmd sync --exclude static/js  --cf-invalidate static/
  s3://mybucket/static/`
- `s3cmd sync --exclude /static/js 
  --cf-invalidate static/ s3://mybucket/static/`
- `s3cmd sync --exclude=static/js  --cf-invalidate static/ s3://mybucket/static/`
- `s3cmd sync --exclude=/static/js  --cf-invalidate static/
  s3://mybucket/static/`

But none of them work. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

These days, it is recommended to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) rather than `s3cmd`.

For details on the `aws s3 sync` command, see: [AWS CLI S3 sync](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)

For filtering rules, see: [Use of Exclude and Include Filters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters)

Comment: Yes I would love to. However, `aws s3 sync` does not have a flag right now which allows for invalidating cloudfront caches.

Comment: Correct. You would need to call [`aws cloudfront create-invalidation`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudfront/create-invalidation.html).

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out if my local directory is static/ then the exclude pattern does not need to include static...